# PowerShell: Match Expression Against Text File Using String-Select

Tags: regex, powershell, multiline

I'm trying to use *Select-String* in PowerShell to extract lines from a text document containing entries from a change log. I've included a sample, below.

The PS command `Select-String "REAPER.*(19|20)" "d:\reaper 6.x versions.txt"` successfully extracts the first line of each log entry (e.g. *REAPER v.6.11 - May 24, 2020*)  but I also need the second line from each entry.

I've tried `Select-String "REAPER.*(19|20)\n.*" "d:\reaper 6.x versions.txt"` and similar but they return blanks or errors.

Stumped.

```
REAPER v6.11 - May 24, 2020
The Gone-Away World
Downloads:
Windows (12MB installer)
Windows x64 (13MB installer)
OS X Intel (18MB DMG)
OS X 64-bit Intel (20MB DMG)
OS X 64-bit Intel (20MB DMG, notarized for Catalina)
Linux x86_64 (11MB .tar.xz)
Linux i686 (11MB .tar.xz)
Linux armv7l (9MB .tar.xz)
Linux aarch64 (9MB .tar.xz)
Changes:
Appearance: add Theme Color Controls window for per-theme brightness/contrast/gamma/color adjustment



REAPER v6.10 - May 9, 2020
The Gone-Away World
Downloads:
Windows (12MB installer)
Windows x64 (13MB installer)
OS X Intel (18MB DMG)
OS X 64-bit Intel (20MB DMG)
OS X 64-bit Intel (20MB DMG, notarized for Catalina)
Linux x86_64 (11MB .tar.xz)
Linux i686 (11MB .tar.xz)
Linux armv7l (9MB .tar.xz)
Linux aarch64 (9MB .tar.xz)
Changes:
ARA: preserve edits when user applies timing changes to media or imports as MIDI
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
PS> Get-Content "d:\reaper 6.x versions.txt" -Raw | Select-String "REAPER.*(?:19|20)(?:\r?\n.*)?" -AllMatches | Foreach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
REAPER v6.11 - May 24, 2020
The Gone-Away World
REAPER v6.10 - May 9, 2020
The Gone-Away World
```

**NOTE**:

- `Get-Content $file -Raw` will read in the whole file as a single string, not an array of lines, so that the pattern could match multiple lines within one match operation
- `REAPER.*(?:19|20)(?:\r?\n.*)?` pattern will match from `REAPER` till the `19` or `20` and then an optional sequence of a CRLF or LF line ending and any zero or more chars other than a newline.

See [the regex demo online](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=REAPER.*%28%3F%3A19%7C20%29%28%3F%3A%5Cr%3F%5Cn.*%29%3F&i=REAPER%20v6.11%20-%20May%2024%2C%202020%0D%0AThe%20Gone-Away%20World%0D%0ADownloads%3A%0D%0AWindows%20%2812MB%20installer%29%0D%0AWindows%20x64%20%2813MB%20installer%29%0D%0AOS%20X%20Intel%20%2818MB%20DMG%29%0D%0AOS%20X%2064-bit%20Intel%20%2820MB%20DMG%29%0D%0AOS%20X%2064-bit%20Intel%20%2820MB%20DMG%2C%20notarized%20for%20Catalina%29%0D%0ALinux%20x86_64%20%2811MB%20.tar.xz%29%0D%0ALinux%20i686%20%2811MB%20.tar.xz%29%0D%0ALinux%20armv7l%20%289MB%20.tar.xz%29%0D%0ALinux%20aarch64%20%289MB%20.tar.xz%29%0D%0AChanges%3A%0D%0AAppearance%3A%20add%20Theme%20Color%20Controls%20window%20for%20per-theme%20brightness%2Fcontrast%2Fgamma%2Fcolor%20adjustment%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0AREAPER%20v6.10%20-%20May%209%2C%202020%0D%0AThe%20Gone-Away%20World%0D%0ADownloads%3A%0D%0AWindows%20%2812MB%20installer%29%0D%0AWindows%20x64%20%2813MB%20installer%29%0D%0AOS%20X%20Intel%20%2818MB%20DMG%29%0D%0AOS%20X%2064-bit%20Intel%20%2820MB%20DMG%29%0D%0AOS%20X%2064-bit%20Intel%20%2820MB%20DMG%2C%20notarized%20for%20Catalina%29%0D%0ALinux%20x86_64%20%2811MB%20.tar.xz%29%0D%0ALinux%20i686%20%2811MB%20.tar.xz%29%0D%0ALinux%20armv7l%20%289MB%20.tar.xz%29%0D%0ALinux%20aarch64%20%289MB%20.tar.xz%29%0D%0AChanges%3A%0D%0AARA%3A%20preserve%20edits%20when%20user%20applies%20timing%20changes%20to%20media%20or%20imports%20as%20MIDI).

To output the two adjacent lines as two columns for output to a CSV, you may use

```
Get-Content "d:\reaper 6.x versions.txt" -Raw | 
  Select-String "(REAPER.*(?:19|20))(?:\r?\n([^\r\n]*))?" -AllMatches | 
    Foreach {$_.Matches} | 
      Foreach { new-object psobject -Property @{Tool=$_.Groups[1];Name=$_.Groups[2]} } |
        Select Tool,Name | 
         Export-Csv  -NoTypeInformation "d:\reaper 6.x versions.csv"
```

Output:

```
"Tool","Name"
"REAPER v6.11 - May 24, 2020","The Gone-Away World"
"REAPER v6.10 - May 9, 2020","The Gone-Away World"
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Also thanks for the link to regexstorm.net; I use regexer and regex101 and this is a great addition!

Comment: How can I format the output with a comma between the first and second capture groups and a line break between different releases? Basically I want to create a CSV.

Comment: @Helmanfrow I added a snippet how to output the captured values into a CSV.

Comment: Scripting is scripting regardless of language. It's a matter of know what needs to be done in one language or the other to achieve the same results. These same types of questions regularly come upon Python, bash, etc. Q&A as well. PS is just on the box, so why not get into it heavy. Stop using cmd.exe stuff, and always user PowerShell instead and use the PowerShell cmdlets in full (easy to read, and self-documenting), not the aliases, shorthand, or old DOS exes. Well, that last one you'll still find yourself using even in Powershell ttuff.

Answer (score 0):

How about using -context?  0 lines before, 1 after:

```
Select-String "REAPER.*(19|20)" file.txt -Context 0,1

> file.txt:1:REAPER v6.11 - May 24, 2020
  file.txt:2:The Gone-Away World
```

Comment: That works, too! It adds a '>' before every every odd-numbered line, but that's easy enough to remedy.